# Iterate list and add multiple values to python dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a list.

Some of the information is in specific format so it's straighforward but then I need a catcha;; to put anything else so that key will have multiple values but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone explain the best way to do this?

```
dv = 'Not Found'

mydict = {'key1': dv, 
        'key2': dv, 
        'key3': dv,}

for stuff in list6:     
        stringit = str(stuff).strip().replace(' ', '_')
        descriplst.append(stringit)
        for x in descriplst:
            if re.match(regasset, x):
                mydict['key1'] = x
            if re.match(regcid, x):
                mydict['key2'] = x
            else:
                mydict['key3'].append(x)
```

The error I am getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "fixdes.py", line 73, in  mydict['Interconnect'].append(x) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: How is it not working as you expect? Are you getting an error? From looking at what you have posted, `mydict['key3']` is the string 'Not Found'. `mydict['key3'].append(x)` will attempt to call `str.append`, which does not exist. Perhaps you want `mydict['key3']` to be initialized as an empty list?

Comment: The error I am getting is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fixdes.py", line 73, in <module>
    mydict['Interconnect'].append(x)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Okay so I changed it to list and it now works but then from the other two keys are also being added. Does it iterate the whole loop with each list item? How can I get it to stop once it matches something?

Comment: resolved this too. the indents in the code were too far in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string value does not have an append. "key3" value needs to be an empty list to start with. then the append in the else statement will work.
Each value will be added to the end of the list. example output for "key3": ["value1", "value2" ... "value6"]

change mydict to:

```
mydict = {'key1': dv, 
    'key2': dv, 
    'key3': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example where students having the same *grade* are added to a list in dictionary at key=common *grade*.

The *grades* here are key and are mapped to the *name* of the student but if more than one student scores the same grade then their names are added to a list and then that list is assigned to their grade(key).

```
dic = {}

for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    grade = input()

    if grade in dic:
        dic[grade].append(name)
    else:
        dic[grade] = [name]
```

Input:
**5

Harry

37.21

Berry

37.21

Tina

37.2

Akriti

41

Harsh

39**

output:
**{'37.21': ['Harry', 'Berry'], '37.2': ['Tina'], '41': ['Akriti'], '39': ['Harsh']}**